# Isotopy classes of maps from the $3$-sphere to the $6$-sphere

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I read somewhere that the group of isotopy classes of continuous maps from the three-sphere to the six-sphere is infinite cyclic. Why is that?

A reference would also be appreciated.

Comment: Neither of these things answer your question, but may be of interest anyway. According to what is written [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isotopy_(in_topology)), if you require your topological embeddings to be locally flat, then they are all isotopic to the standard embedding. Also, there are exactly two isotopy classes of *smooth* embeddings $S^3 \to S^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in the following paper by André Haefliger:

*Differential embeddings of $S^
n$
in $S
^{n
+
q}$
for $q
≥
2$*, Ann. of Math. 83 (1966) 402–436

From the introduction of the article:

> This paper can be considered as a complement to the fundamental paper
>   of J. Levine [same Ann. (2) 82 (1965), 15–50; MR0180981]. Instead of
>   studying the group $θ_n^q$ of isotopy classes of embedded homotopy
>   $n$-spheres in $S^{n+q}$, we are interested here in the group $C_n^q$
>   of isotopy classes of embeddings of the usual $n$-sphere $S^n$ in
>   $S^{n+q}$. Our main result is the isomorphism of $C_n^q$ with the
>   triad homotopy group $π_{n+1}(G;SO,G_q)$ for $q>2$, where $G_q$ is the
>   space of maps of degree one of $S_{q−1}$ onto itself, and $G$ its
>   stable suspension.

Comment: After chasing references a bit, The paper "Knotted (4k - 1)-Spheres in 6k-Space" by André Haefliger has a nice description of the generator.